# Is a UK Transit visa required by an Indian national travelling from Ireland to India via LHR?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I’m an Indian passport holder with a D category long-stay student visa (Stemp2). I’m going to India via London Heathrow with two hours layover. My [flight details](https://www.kayak.ie/flights/DUB-AMD-29732/2016-01-07/2016-02-10/f8226c72137c32be0c2d0608f54aa38aa).

Will I need a UK Transit visa?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently as a non EU Citizen, you'll need a  [Direct Airside Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa)

Comment: So why was this down voted?